# Replace unknown number of characters in a string with '*' in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a column **MEMO_TXT** has the following text in one **MEMO** table:
`'Password changed from: 12345  to:  abcdefg.'`

How can i replace `12345` and `abcdefg` in
the above text with equally sized `'*'` characters?

like,
    `'Password changed from: 12345  to:  abcdefg.'`
`'Password changed from: *****  to:  *******.'`

The **from** and **to** parts in the above string can vary and i'm not sure how to write an UPDATE query with REPLACE since i have no fixed pattern to look for.

Comment: Oracle really isn't the best place to be doing such manipulations.  A better idea would be to read this record into an app language, e.g. Java, and do the replacement there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If message text is always in that format, good old `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` + `REPLACE` can do the job.

```
SQL> WITH test (col)
  2       AS (SELECT '&message' FROM DUAL),
  3       pos
  4       AS (SELECT col,
  5                  INSTR (col, ':', 1, 1)
  6                     colon_1,
  7                  INSTR (col, ':', 1, 2)
  8                     colon_2,
  9                  LENGTH (col) len
 10             FROM test),
 11       inter
 12       AS (SELECT col,
 13                  trim(SUBSTR (col, colon_1 + 2, colon_2 - 4 - colon_1)) old_pw,
 14                  TRIM (RTRIM (SUBSTR (col, colon_2 + 1, len - colon_2), '.'))
 15                     new_pw
 16             FROM pos)
 17  SELECT REPLACE (REPLACE (col, old_pw, LPAD ('*', LENGTH (old_pw), '*')),
 18                  new_pw,
 19                  LPAD ('*', LENGTH (new_pw), '*')) result
 20    FROM inter;
Enter value for message: Password changed from: 12345  to:  abcdefg.

RESULT
-------------------------------------------
Password changed from: *****  to:  *******.

SQL> /
Enter value for message: Password changed from: abxyz44#  to:  87ZU_3.

RESULT
----------------------------------------------
Password changed from: ********  to:  *******

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using REGEXP_REPLACE function.

Answer (score -1):

```
select rpad('*', 10, '*')
```

I think this link can help you:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions159.htm#SQLRF06103